# Stateful and stateless beans don't saves the state on Wildfly(only singleton saves)

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.1

I have a List of some entities in my bean and two methods:

1. adding new entity instance in the List
2. reading of the List.

On `jboss-as-7.1.11` both stateful or stateless beans works correctly.
But if I have deploy application on `Wildfly 8`, only with using `@Singleton` annotation second method returns collection with to the previously added element.
It seems like in the case of using `@Stateful` or `@Stateless` annotations for each request creates a new instance of bean.

How can I solve it?
I appeal to the ejb via RESTEasy service, if it's important.

Comment: You need to explain more your problem, ist he list you are talking used by different users, or it's the same user who added  the entity who also try to read from the List ?

Comment: It's the same user on the same computer.

Comment: This is wierd, because in the case of @Stateless you must not have the state, so it's your Wildfly behavior which is correct. 
Thus, it seems to me very weird that you have a correct behavior regarding SFSB and incorrect one regarding SLSB for JBOSS, and tottaly the opposite of that for wildfly!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that JBoss uses a stateless session bean pool, which means you are getting "lucky" that it works.  If you add multiple concurrent clients, I suspect that JBoss would also fail.  You should use a singleton session bean if maintaining state across requests and clients is important.

Comment: Well but what about 'statefull'?

Comment: Per section 8.3 ("EJB Resource Classes") of the JAX-RS 2.0 spec, "[...] products that support EJB must also support the use of stateless and singleton session beans as root resource classes".  The spec makes no mention of stateful, so it's not spec-defined behavior, and I'm not familiar enough with JBoss to explain what's happening in that case.

Comment: My best guess is that it ignores the stateful annotation altogether, so it falls back to default behavior (as if you had no EJB component-defining annotation at all), which is to create a new instance for each request.